# Writing a flood-fill method in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, flood-fill

In order to write a flood-fill method of mine in Swift, I am trying as a first step to compile the code I found here:
[iOS Swift Flood fill algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580688/ios-swift-flood-fill-algorithm)
So that I can see how it works.
But I get errors.

The first one being: Value of type 'UIImage' has no member 'createARGBBitmapContext' Since I have no experience with extensions I may well be doing something wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `createARGBBitmapContext()` is apparently a local function in the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580688/ios-swift-flood-fill-algorithm project, but the definition is not shown. Why don't you leave a comment at that question and ask for clarification?

Comment: It comes from [Apple Q&A 1509](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1509/_index.html) which the author of that question obviously ported to Swift. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685598/creating-uiimage-from-nsdata-created-from-buffer-returns-nil/26686111#26686111 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661023/change-color-of-certain-pixels-in-a-uiimage/31661519#31661519 for examples of manipulating pixel buffer in Swift.

Comment: I have already left a comment on the question as Martin suggests. Thanks for the couple of links, in Rob's comment, I hope that will allow me to make a few more steps.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661023/change-color-of-certain-pixels-in-a-uiimage/31661519#31661519 suggested above is helpful. But how do I set the resulting image?
My code is:
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0)
view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
let originalImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
let newImage = processPixelsInImage(originalImage:UIImage)
let imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView.init(image: newImage)
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
I feel the last 2 instructions are not right.